# getting error while deploying express app on heroku Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-Parser'

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, web-deployment

**This is my first deployment and getting an error please help me .as you see in the picture cookie-parser is already listed in the package.josn but it is not installing as dependencies on Heroku and getting errors Cannot find module 'cookie-Parser' and the thing which I noticed in Heroku is P is capital in parser "cookie-Parser" which is a little bit different from the official module spelling. this is my package.json file where cookie parser is listed and I tried both without using and with using @types/cookie-parser but nothing works.

```js
{
  "name": "medicare",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Medical solution right at home",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "medical"
  ],
  "author": "Aman",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cron": "^1.8.2",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "ical-generator": "^3.1.1",
    "joi": "^17.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.12",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "node-geocoder": "^3.28.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "passport": "^0.5.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "paytmchecksum": "^1.5.0",
    "peer": "^0.6.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.0"
  }
}
```

and this is the error that I am getting and it is successfully build on Heroku but getting errors while running the app.

```js
2022-01-18T05:32:19.185909+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-18T05:32:22.111839+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-18T05:32:23.773056+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-18T05:32:23.773071+00:00 app[web.1]: > medicare@1.0.0 start /app
2022-01-18T05:32:23.773072+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2022-01-18T05:32:23.773072+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-18T05:32:24.700130+00:00 app[web.1]: Router is loaded.
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709241+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709243+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709244+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709244+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709244+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-Parser'
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709245+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709245+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/controllers/users_controller.js
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709246+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/users.js
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709246+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/index.js
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709246+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709247+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709247+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709248+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709248+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709249+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/controllers/users_controller.js:3:20)
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709249+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709249+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709249+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709250+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709250+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709250+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709250+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709251+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/controllers/users_controller.js',2022-01-18T05:32:24.709251+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/routes/users.js',
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709251+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/routes/index.js',
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709251+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/index.js'
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709252+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2022-01-18T05:32:24.709252+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-01-18T05:32:24.721580+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-01-18T05:32:24.721787+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2022-01-18T05:32:24.726938+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! medicare@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2022-01-18T05:32:24.727001+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2022-01-18T05:32:24.727073+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-01-18T05:32:24.727122+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the medicare@1.0.0 start script.
2022-01-18T05:32:24.727169+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-01-18T05:32:24.732468+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-18T05:32:24.732543+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-01-18T05:32:24.732575+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-18T05_32_24_727Z-debug.log
2022-01-18T05:32:24.866783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-18T05:32:24.969112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-18T05:32:51.119702+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=medicare-solution.herokuapp.com request_id=45a34311-4c81-48a2-b1f1-d35c4bacbc6d fwd="47.15.123.35" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-18T05:32:52.627349+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=medicare-solution.herokuapp.com request_id=3c1c5d1f-1826-4233-a4e2-8a7473d565a0 fwd="47.15.123.35" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Maybe you misspelled it when requiring the module: `require('cookie-Parser')` instead of `require('cookie-parser')`?

Comment: Thank u so much dear ...it worked.it was a silly mistake but this is my first time so .but again thanku